# Why req body is {} even though I send the data with API Post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm creating my own API (with express) and react.js application. However, when I send the data from the react app, it is not retrieved by the server. Here's my code:

POST Request Client Side:

```
async function sendRequest(text) {

    const url = "http://localhost:51515/initialize"
    const settings = {
        method: "POST",
        body: {
            text: text
        }
    }
        
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, settings)
        return await response.json()
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Server Side POST Request Retrieval:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 51515

app.use(express.json())

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`API initialized on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
)

app.post('/initialize', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // The log output is {}
})
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: perhaps you aren't sending JSON - try `express.text()` body parser instead - or, of course, send JSON

Comment: oh, I see ... you need `body: JSON.stringify({ text: text })` (or just `body: JSON.stringify({ text })` if you want)

Comment: Well still there's no value, it didn't change anything.

Comment: you didn't tell the server you're sending JSON ... `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }` - it's in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add these parameters to your settings object.

```js
const settings = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        text: text
    }),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
}
```

Comment: Did it but now it gives this error: Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Efe, your Express api and React app are not serving in same server. You can easily solve this problem using Cors. Just "npm install cors" to your backend server then "const cors = require('cors')" and "app.use(cors())" it.

Comment: Nothing much :)